# Simplifying Puppet Manifest

Tags: puppet

I want to provision multiple sets of things on a server using existing puppet modules the simplest example would be:

```
file { "/var/www/MYVARIABLEHERE":
    ensure => "directory",
}
mysql::db { MYVARIABLEHERE:
    user     => MYVARIABLEHERE,
    password => MYVARIABLEHERE,
    host     => 'localhost',
    grant    => ['all'],
}
```

Is there a way to abstract this out so that I can have say an array of pre defined options and then pass them into existing puppet modules so I don't end up with a manifest file that's thousands of lines long?

As per the answer below I have setup:

```
define mySites {
  mysql::db { $name:
    user     => $name,
    password => $name,
    host     => 'localhost',
    grant    => ['all'],
  }

  file { "/var/www/${name}.drupal.dev":
    ensure => "directory",
  }
}
```

I then call:

```
mySites {"site": $name => "test", }
```

and get the following error:

```
Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at 'name'; expected '}'
```

Comment: Remove the `$` in front of `$name`... I would still suggest a different name for the variable not `name`....

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `define` type to simplify as much :

```
define mydef( $usern, $passn) {
  file { "/var/www/$usern":
     ensure => "directory",
  }
  mysql::db { $usern :
      user => $usern,
      password => $passn,
      host => "localhost",
      grant => ['all'],
  }
}

# You have to call the define type for each cases.
mydef{"u1": usern => "john", password => "pass", }

# It might be possible to provide multiple arrays to a define
# type if you use puppet's future parser
```

Comment: You can't call `$name` like that, it is a puppet global variable... Use a different name for the variable.

Comment: I replaced the $name vars with $drupal and I still get the same error. My full script is here - http://pastie.org/private/ku1ny2unv1mofejmpwx4oq - I really appreciate you help so far.

Comment: My fault. Silly.  There shouldn't be dollar sign `$` in front of `drupal`. It should be written, mySites{"site": drupal => "test",}. I have edited my answer....

Comment: Using your example I know get "Invalid parameter password", would it make any difference that I'm using vagrant to do all this? My puppet version is 2.7.19. Sorry to be a pain!

Comment: I am not sure of vagrant, I have never used it. Not sure what to suggest here. May be you can post the entire error in pastebin or somthing...